# Вертикальное позиционирование относительно иконки

Tags: html

```css
.services-info {
  margin: 70px 0px 55px 0px;
}

.services__item {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
}

.services__text-2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
        

<div class="services-info">
                <div class="services__item">
                    <img src="img/icons/services-1.svg" alt="">
                    
                    <h3 class="services__title-2">Создание сайтов</h3> 
                    <div class="text-text">
                        <p class="services__text-2">Lorem Ipsum - это текст- "рыба", часто используе в печати и вэб-дизайне.</p>
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: было бы неплохо добавить ваш css

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь за оформление :)
Пока ещё не разобрался

Comment: Вы уверены что это все стили?

Comment: @InDevX
Я уже просто большинство стёр
Я просто перепробовал большинство методов, но у меня всё равно блок с <p> всё равно стоит на одном месте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оберните дивом и подберите `padding-top`.

```css
.services__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.services__item img {
  display: block;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.services__item .info {
  padding-top: 2.25em;
}

.services__item .info h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="services__item">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/QYNfaWW.png" alt="">
  <div class="info">
    <h3 class="services__title-2">Создание сайтов</h3>
    <div class="text-text">
      <p class="services__text-2">Lorem Ipsum - это текст- "рыба", часто используе в печати и вэб-дизайне.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)